# Where to buy cheap motors and mechanical parts for hobby robotics applications?

Tags: mobile-robot, arduino, motor, microcontroller, wheel

My kids want to get into robotics, where Online can I buy the motors (dc,ac,stepper...) and mechanical assembly (nuts, bolts, sheet metal, springs, rods...) for a very affordable price, you know I just want to get a big box of all this stuff and let them tinker around with it. Even where to find cheap microcontrollers, leds, wheel bearings, wheels and tracks, sensors...

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Kay Bei, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Comment: I thought at first you were talking about something like Vex Robotics, but you're mentioning AC motors, which would generally be beyond the scope of a student/introductory kit.

Answer (score -1):

Go to ebay and type things like arduino robot into the search bar and use search descriptions. Anything you click on will if you scroll down have a section labeled people who bought this also bought. Its a way to do a tour of  what people have been buying.